# How can I get multiple outputs from single operation?

Tags: r, lapply, spatstat

These are the codes that have been written to analyze within and between interactions of different species.

in this code, I tried to get separate outputs from each analyzes unsuccessfully.

```
  lapply(data.list, function(x) {            
    grp <- factor(x$species)                 
    window <- ripras(x$utmX, x$utmY)         
    pp.grp <- ppp(x$utmX, x$utmY, window=window, marks=grp) 
    split.grp <- split(pp.grp)               
    L <- (alltypes(pp.grp, "L"))         
    LE <- alltypes(pp.grp, Lcross, nsim = 100, envelope = TRUE)  
    return("L", "LE")
})
plot(L[1])
```

So my question is how I can get multiple outputs from a single operation?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to handle multiple outputs from a function in R is to put
the results in a list and return that. Hopefully this can inspire you:

```r
f <- function(x){
  L <- x
  LE <- matrix(x, 2, 2)
  rslt <- list(L = L, LE = LE)
  return(rslt)
}
y <- f(7)
```

Now y is a list with two elements: L and LE

```r
y
#> $L
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> $LE
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    7    7
#> [2,]    7    7
```

Use `$` to get a named element (in this case `L` – same as `y[[1]]`):

```r
y$L
#> [1] 7
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Ege Rubak. I got this error related to envelope or something: "Error in envelopeEngine(X = X, fun = fun, simul = simrecipe, nsim = nsim,  : 
  Exceeded maximum number of errors". Can you tell me it is because of what?

Comment: Without the entire code giving the error it is almost impossible to guess what the problem is. Can you reproduce the error with a built in dataset or some simulated data?